# Element ScrollView must be declared issue

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, scrollview

Android studio give me an error when i try to build my code:
`

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute ScrollView@package value=(com.applikacia.loginandroidsql) from AndroidManifest.xml:3:1-71:14
    is also present at [com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0] AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-42 value=(com.google.android.material).
    Attributes of <manifest> elements are not merged.
```

`
and in the problems tab it says: Element ScrollView must be declared

Also this is my AndroidManifest.xml file:
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/editName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:textColor="#FF192133"
            android:textColorHint="#A0192133"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/editPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="#FF192133"
            android:textColorHint="#A0192133"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/editEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="#FF192133"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColorHint="#A0192133"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
            android:text="SIGN IN"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

`

I already tried like every solution found online but none of theme seem to work.
Im also new to android development so i really have no what might be wrong even after reading the build error.

Comment: Try adding android.useAndroidX=true and android.enableJetifier=true in gradle.properties file.

Comment: you don't add layout in manifest file

Comment: @Manjeetdeswal where should i place it then?